# Estimating the temperature of the sun using Wien's displacement law

Tags: photons, temperature, sun

After previously deriving the frequency distribution of photons as

$$u(\omega,T) = \frac{\omega^3\hbar}{\pi^2 v^3}\frac{1}{e^{-B K_B T} - 1}$$

I have been asked to estimate the temperature of the sun using

$$\lambda = \frac{B}{T} $$

where $B = 2.9 \times 10^{-3}$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $\lambda$ is the _peak_  wavelength of the blackbody spectrum.

Comment: The wavelength will not be given to us in the test.

Comment: What is given, then?

Comment: b, and that equation we have derived

Comment: I don't see what you're asking, then.

Comment: Can you maybe provide a sample problem that illustrates the particular thing you're trying to do?

Comment: Some things you are supposed to know as a physicist. Some numerical values, orders of magnitude.